# setter error when trying to access method of child class in polymorphic array (java)

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, polymorphism

I'm making a programme with parent class Item, and child classes Game and Album and I've stored the objects in a polymorphic arraylist of type item in a class called library.

I've added a few more variables in the child class of games for example and when I try to edit the variable unique to the game class ( called ageRating ) through a method called editAgeRating with a setter I'm getting an error. eclipse says to add the method in the parent class and when i do it still doesn't overwrite the previous ageRating variable.

I'm pretty sure It's to do with the fact that I have an arraylist of type item and I'm trying to access something unique to the Game class but I don't know how to solve it. (I've updated my post, I initially had i.getAgeRating(newAgeRating) in my editAgeRating method and I've returned it to set. I was messing about with it and I forgot to change it back)

Help would be greatly appreciated

I'll post the code down below

```
public class Item {

private int id;
private String title;
private String genre;
private int yearReleased;

public Item() {

}

public Item(int id, String title, String genre, int yearReleased) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.yearReleased = yearReleased;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getGenre() {
    return genre;
}

public void setGenre(String genre) {
    this.genre = genre;
}

public int getYearReleased() {
    return yearReleased;
}

public void setYearReleased(int yearReleased) {
    this.yearReleased = yearReleased;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((genre == null) ? 0 : genre.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + id;
    result = prime * result + ((title == null) ? 0 : title.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + yearReleased;
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Item other = (Item) obj;
    if (genre == null) {
        if (other.genre != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!genre.equals(other.genre))
        return false;
    if (id != other.id)
        return false;
    if (title == null) {
        if (other.title != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!title.equals(other.title))
        return false;
    if (yearReleased != other.yearReleased)
        return false;
    return true;
}

public String toString() {
    return " | ID: " + id + " | Title: " + title + " | Genre:  " + genre + " | Year Released: " + yearReleased; 
}
```

}

```
public class Game extends Item{

private int ageRating;
private String developer;

public Game() {

}

public Game(int id, String title, String genre, int yearReleased, int ageRating, String developer) {

    super(id, title, genre, yearReleased);
    this.ageRating = ageRating;
    this.developer = developer;

    new Library(this);

}

public int getAgeRating() {
    return ageRating;
}

public void setAgeRating(int ageRating) {
    this.ageRating = ageRating;
}

public String getDeveloper() {
    return developer;
}

public void setDeveloper(String developer) {
    this.developer = developer;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = super.hashCode();
    result = prime * result + ageRating;
    result = prime * result + ((developer == null) ? 0 : developer.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (!super.equals(obj))
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Game other = (Game) obj;
    if (ageRating != other.ageRating)
        return false;
    if (developer == null) {
        if (other.developer != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!developer.equals(other.developer))
        return false;
    return true;
}

public String toString() {
    return "Game: " + super.toString() + " | Age Rating: " + ageRating + " | Developer: " + developer;
}
```

}

```
public class Library {

static ArrayList<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();

public Library(Item object) {
    itemList.add(object);
}

public static void printItems() {
    for(Item i: itemList) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

public static void removeItem(int id) { 
    for(int i = itemList.size() -1 ; i > -1; i--) { // start backwards as problem removing when looping foreward
        if( id == itemList.get(i).getId() )
            itemList.remove(i);
    }
}

public static void editID(int searchId, int newId) {
    for(Item i: itemList) {
        if( i.getId() == searchId) {
            i.setId(newId);
        }
    }
}

public static void editTitle(int searchId, String newTitle) {
    for(Item i: itemList) {
        if( i.getId() == searchId);
            i.setTitle(newTitle);
    }
}

public static void editGenre(int searchId, String newGenre) {
    for(Item i: itemList) {
        if( i.getId() == searchId);
            i.setGenre(newGenre);
    }
}

public static void editYearReleased(int searchId, int newYearReleased) {
    for(Item i: itemList) {
        if( i.getId() == searchId);
            i.setYearReleased(newYearReleased);
    }
}

public static void editAgeRating(int searchId, int newAgeRating) {
    for (Item i: itemList) {
        if( i.getId() == searchId)
            i.setAgeRating(newAgeRating);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see there are more than one problem in your code:

1) In your editAgeRating method, you are not calling the setter, but you are currently calling the getter. And there is no such method in your class (getAgeRating method which takes a newAgeRating parameter). Your getter method does not need parameter. Which means, method signatures are different.

2) In your editAgeRating method, while iterating over list of items, you treat those each individual objects as an Item, not as a Game object.

I think there is also a misunderstanding of polymorphism. I suggest you to read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).

To give you a simple example, all animals "move". However a bird fly, a fish swims, a human being walks, a rabbit hops, i.e. each instance of animal implement move method differently although they all have a move method.

Cheers.

EDIT

There could be more than one solution to this problem. Here is a couple:

1) Define Item as an Abstract class and add editAgeRating method into that class as an abstract method.

2) Define an interface, which has editAgeRating method. Then make your Item and Game classes implement that interface.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me, I accidently left in my getter instead of a setter as I was trying something before I posted the question and I forgot to change it back. I apologize for the imistake  however the problem still persists. it still says the method is undefined for type item

Comment: Since the 1st possibility is our of the way, then you can check out the 2nd possible reason above. You used the type Item in the loop, not Game. So you should not expect it to magically find the method in the latter.

Comment: Thank you for the help man, I really appreciate it. I managed to change the value. What fixed it was adding the abstract class and then adding setAgeRating method in Item.

Comment: I am glad if it helped. If this helped the issue, please accept my answer. Thank you.